# Can't pass parameters through React Navigation TabBar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Can't send any parameters with react-navigation 5x.
Tried everything on documentation. Don't know what's wrong.

I will share you all my route structure.

My ApplicationNavigator.js: I'm using drawer content with tabbar navigator at the same time.   OrderNavigator is a tabnavigator, Dashboard is stacknavigator.

```
const ApplicationNavigator = () => {
  const [isApplicationLoaded, setIsApplicationLoaded] = useState(false)
  const applicationIsLoading = useSelector((state) => state.startup.loading)

 return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Order" component={OrderNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

export default ApplicationNavigator
```

My OrderNavigator.js: This is my tab.screen structure.

```
const ScreenA = () => {
  return (
    .....
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={headerStyle_1}
        name="Orders"
        component={IndexOrderContainer}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const ScreenB = () => {
  ....
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={headerStyle_1}
        name="New Order"
        component={AddOrderContainer}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const OrderNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator headerMode={'none'}>
      <Tab.Screen name="OrderList" component={ScreenA} />
      <Tab.Screen name="NewOrder" component={ScreenB} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

export default OrderNavigator
```

I'm trying to make redirect with code below. I'm using it with my order listing page, and trying to redirect to "order detail" page onclick. (with tab navigator.)

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() =>
      navigation.navigate('NewOrder', {
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      })
    }
    style={[styles.ListItem]}
    button
    key={`order${index}`}
  >
```

And my response, when try to navigate with parameters is.
But you can see that my params is "undefined" with response.

```
const AddOrderContainer = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(route)
  }, [route])
....
....
Object {
  "key": "New Order-mafygLVPzFO1rVOhj1zVH",
  "name": "New Order",
  "params": undefined,
}
```